# Sublime Text 2 Code Hinting

Tags: html, laravel, sublimetext2, code-hinting, codehighlighter

This is my first time with Sublime Text 2. I am trying it because people say it works best with Laravel. I have also installed some package such as Laravel Blade, Laravel Snippets, and etc.

However, when I tried to play around with it, I found that it's code hinting doesn't work every well as compare to Dreamweaver. Let say for example, if I want to type "", the code hint does show the "h1" suggestion. But when I want to add in more thing into the h1 tag like style and etc, the code hint doesn't help at all. Also, I found that jQuery code hint doesn't work at all.

Am I missing something? Or it is the actual behavior of Sublime Text? Is it possible to have the code hinting works like Dreamweaver and even better with Laravel support in Sublime Text?

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend to view this tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/perfect-workflow-in-sublime-text-free-course/. This is very useful tutorial for everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text is a very powerful editor. But it is not the same thing as an IDE like Visual Studio, phpStorm.

Compare to IDE, it is light weighted, but still very powerful.

Here is one good article on how to setup a good workflow on sublime you may have a look.

[Perfect Workflow in Sublime Text](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/perfect-workflow-in-sublime-text-free-course/)

You need to install some plugins to make the editor customized as what you want.

For code completion you can try plugin called "Emmet" which was "zencode" before.

Here is the [documentation](http://docs.emmet.io/) of how to make your coding more efficient by using "Emmet"

After reading this, trying some plugin, I believe you will find lots of funs on using it. Enjoy~

Comment: Yeah, some plugins makes ST stronger, like vintage, code intel, package control, sidebar and emet

Answer (score 0):

For the Laravel integration, check out [the laravel IDE helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) and use it along with [Sublime CodeIntel](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel).  The IDE helper is installed in your laravel project via composer and is used to generate a helper file that is used by the CodeIntel plugin to provide better completion support.  As for the HTML completions, check out the various HTML packages for sublime, such as HTML5 and HTML attributes.  I haven't used those ones in particular so I can't say how well they work, but there is bound to be a package for ST to give you what you want.